# AngularJS - manipulate variables outside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I am tryingto make a service that will allow me to manipulate variables outside `ng-view`. I made a service with `factory`, but I am at a loss how to transport variables from child-controller to parent (at least, this is the method I have been able to find by reading q&a's here on SO).

For example I would like to be able to manipulate `{{ siteName }}`, which is located outside `ng-view` from my `articleCtrl` controller.

This is what I did:

```js
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'blogCtrl'
]);

blogApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/page', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/page.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            }).
            when('/page/:pagePermaLink', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/page.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            }).
            when('/article/:articlePermaLink', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/article.html',
                controller: 'articleCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/page/404',
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/404.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

blogApp.factory('templateService', function() {
    return {
        siteName:'',
        tagline:'',
        pageName:''
    };
});

function articleCtrl($scope, templateService) {
   $scope.template = templateService;
}

function templateCtrl($scope, templateService) {
   $scope.template = templateService;
}

var templateCtrl = angular.module('templateCtrl', []);
var blogCtrl = angular.module('blogCtrl', []);

blogCtrl.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'templateService',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http, templateService) {
    $scope.siteName = "Something awesomediculous";
}]);

blogCtrl.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    // ...
}]);

blogApp.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, templateService) {
    // ...
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="blogApp" data-ng-controller="templateCtrl">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>{{ pageName + " - " + siteName }}</title>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

 <base href="/angular_blog/">

</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <h1>{{ siteName }}</h1>
  <p>{{ tagline }}</p>
 </header>

 <main id="content" data-ng-view></main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to bind the service to your scope where you are supposed to do it, in your templateCtrl.

Also if you have `$scope.template.myname` you should use `{{template.name}}`.

See working code below.

Btw, there seems to be some unnecessary functions in your code

```js
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'blogCtrl'
]);

blogApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/page', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/page.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            }).
            when('/page/:pagePermaLink', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/page.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            }).
            when('/article/:articlePermaLink', {
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/article.html',
                controller: 'articleCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/page/404',
                templateUrl: '/angular_blog/assets/templates/404.html',
                controller: 'pageCtrl'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

blogApp.factory('templateService', function() {
    return {
        siteName:'mysitename',
        tagline:'mytagline',
        pageName:'mypagename'
    };
});

function articleCtrl($scope, templateService) {
   $scope.template = templateService;
}

function templateCtrl($scope, templateService) {
   $scope.template = templateService;
}

var templateCtrl = angular.module('templateCtrl', []);
var blogCtrl = angular.module('blogCtrl', []);

blogCtrl.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', 'templateService',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http, templateService) {
    $scope.siteName = "Something awesomediculous";
}]);

blogCtrl.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    // ...
}]);

blogApp.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, templateService) {
    // ...
// added this line:
   $scope.template = templateService;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="blogApp" data-ng-controller="templateCtrl">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>{{ pageName + " - " + siteName }}</title>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

 <base href="/angular_blog/">

</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <h1>{{ template.siteName }}</h1>
  <p>{{ template.tagline }}</p>
 </header>

 <main id="content" data-ng-view></main>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You, sir, saved my day! I didn't "forget" to bind anything, I just had no idea I was supposed to :D

Answer (score 1):

You could move the siteName property to templateCtrl which will then be available across all views.

```
blogApp.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, templateService) {

   // this is important as updates from child will not take effect if done on primitives
   $scope.site = {};
   $scope.site.siteName = "Something awesomediculous";
});
```

Comment: Okay, I might not simply understand the workflow here then, but doesn't this do the exact opposite of what I want? In my question I ask how to do it _from articleCtrl_ . Moving the variable definition line to templateCtrl makes it non-dynamic in this template-model, or no?

Comment: Anything from templateCtrl is inherited to child controller and any updates to variable from articleCtrl will update the parent. So for instance if the siteName is updated from articleCtrl and the view is changed then it will be reflected in the new ctrl as it also inherits the same variable.

Comment: Aaaah okay, then I think I get it! Thank you :)

Comment: Okay, I tried what you wrote, and when I then do `$scope.siteName = "something";` in articleCtrl, nothing happens.

Comment: you have to use the object $scope.site = {}; as primitives will not work. check this link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1